# Memory layout of android dex files

Tags: dalvik, dex, memory-layout

I have been reading up on android infrastructure the past few day and I came across the understanding that the Dalvik virtual machine is a register based machine as opposed to the conventional stack based virtual machine. In that case, what would the memory layout of dex files be like? In a typical C program, its memory layout is in the form of data, text, heap and stack. Is that the same for dex files as well. And if its so, how does the Dalvik virtual machine process such files?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Android runs on the Linux kernel. So, the Linux kernel is responsible for managing physical memory. How the android ART manages the memory interaction with kernel is not familiar to me. But, a priori, it should provide the same memory layout that is required by a Linux binary (text, data, heap, stack, shared memory). 
Well, actually I got the confirmation of it by viewing a memory map of a process (`cat /proc/pid/maps`) gives you the similar memory layout to a typical Linux program but with an important number of shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The .dex format is [fully described in the official Android docs](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html), so you can take a look there. As a quick graphical intro, there's also a great PDF with an [annotated diagram showing a minimal "hello world" .dex file](https://github.com/corkami/pics/blob/3cb08bc92e6c7508a30ca0d9f5f8a3319a300591/binary/DalvikEXecutable.pdf), by [Ange Albertini](https://github.com/corkami).